# Typescript Sudoku problem outputting incomplete boards

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I've managed to convert a js sudoku generator into a ts generator for some practice and the only problem I'm having is getting it to output only complete boards. Right now, it's outputting boards regardless if they're complete and I have to refresh until one board is correct.

I'm not sure how to write the following function so that it only outputs full boards:

```
function fillBoard(puzzleArray: number[][]): number[][] {
    if (nextEmptyCell(puzzleArray).colIndex === -1) return puzzleArray;

    let emptyCell = nextEmptyCell(puzzleArray);

    for (var num in shuffle(numArray)) {
      if (safeToPlace(puzzleArray, emptyCell, numArray[num])) {
        puzzleArray[emptyCell.rowIndex][emptyCell.colIndex] = numArray[num];
        fillBoard(puzzleArray);
      } 
    }

    return puzzleArray;
  }
```

Here is all my code:

```
import { Box } from "./Box";

export function Board() {
  let BLANK_BOARD = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  ];

  let NEW_BOARD = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  ];

  let counter: number = 0;
  let check: number[];
  const numArray: number[] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

  function rowSafe(
    puzzleArray: number[][],
    emptyCell: { rowIndex: number; colIndex: number },
    num: number
  ): boolean {
    return puzzleArray[emptyCell.rowIndex].indexOf(num) == -1;
  }

  function colSafe(
    puzzleArray: number[][],
    emptyCell: { rowIndex: number; colIndex: number },
    num: number
  ): boolean {
    let test = puzzleArray.flat();
    for (let i = emptyCell.colIndex; i < test.length; i += 9) {
      if (test[i] === num) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  function regionSafe(
    puzzleArray: number[][],
    emptyCell: { rowIndex: number; colIndex: number },
    num: number
  ): boolean {
    const rowStart: number = emptyCell.rowIndex - (emptyCell.rowIndex % 3);
    const colStart: number = emptyCell.colIndex - (emptyCell.colIndex % 3);

    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        if (puzzleArray[rowStart + i][colStart + j] === num) {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  console.log(rowSafe(BLANK_BOARD, { rowIndex: 4, colIndex: 6 }, 5));
  console.log(colSafe(BLANK_BOARD, { rowIndex: 2, colIndex: 3 }, 4));
  console.log(regionSafe(BLANK_BOARD, { rowIndex: 5, colIndex: 6 }, 5));

  function safeToPlace(
    puzzleArray: number[][],
    emptyCell: { rowIndex: number; colIndex: number },
    num: number
  ): boolean {
    return (
      regionSafe(puzzleArray, emptyCell, num) &&
      rowSafe(puzzleArray, emptyCell, num) &&
      colSafe(puzzleArray, emptyCell, num)
    );
  }

  console.log(safeToPlace(BLANK_BOARD, { rowIndex: 5, colIndex: 6 }, 5));

  function nextEmptyCell(puzzleArray: number[][]): {
    colIndex: number;
    rowIndex: number;
  } {
    let emptyCell = { rowIndex: -1, colIndex: -1 };
    for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
        if (puzzleArray[i][j] === 0) {
          return { rowIndex: i, colIndex: j };
        }
      }
    }
    return emptyCell;
  }

  function shuffle(array: number[]): number[] {
    // using Array sort and Math.random

    let shuffledArr = array.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random());
    return shuffledArr;
  }

  function fillBoard(puzzleArray: number[][]): number[][] {
    if (nextEmptyCell(puzzleArray).colIndex === -1) return puzzleArray;

    let emptyCell = nextEmptyCell(puzzleArray);

    for (var num in shuffle(numArray)) {
      if (safeToPlace(puzzleArray, emptyCell, numArray[num])) {
        puzzleArray[emptyCell.rowIndex][emptyCell.colIndex] = numArray[num];
        fillBoard(puzzleArray);
      } else {
        puzzleArray[emptyCell.rowIndex][emptyCell.colIndex] = 0;
      }
    }

    return puzzleArray;
  }

  console.log(nextEmptyCell(BLANK_BOARD));

  NEW_BOARD = fillBoard(BLANK_BOARD);

  function fullBoard(puzzleArray: number[][]): boolean {
    return puzzleArray.every((row) => row.every((col) => col !== 0));
  }

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        height: "450px",
        width: "450px",
        display: "inline-grid",
        gap: "10px",
        gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(9,50px)",
        gridTemplateRows: "repeat(9,50px)",
        position: "absolute",
        top: "30px",
        left: "0px",
        right: "0px",
        marginLeft: "auto",
        marginRight: "auto",
      }}
    >
      {NEW_BOARD.flat().map((item) => (
        <Box i={item} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function will return an incomplete board when it turns out there is no way to add a digit in a free cell that will be valid.

To solve that, your function should:

- implement proper backtracking, i.e. taking back a move that didn't work out
- Have the function return a boolean (for success/failure) -- there is no need for it to return `puzzleArray`, since that array is mutated inplace, so the caller has access to the changes.

  - This also means that `NEW_BOARD = fillBoard(BLANK_BOARD);` is having as side effect that `NEW_BOARD` and `BLANK_BOARD` reference the *same* board, and it is *not* blank any more (so the name is misleading).
- break/return out of the loop when there is success.

Here is the adapted implementation:

```
function fillBoard(puzzleArray: number[][]): boolean {
    if (nextEmptyCell(puzzleArray).colIndex === -1) return true; // boolean

    let emptyCell = nextEmptyCell(puzzleArray);

    for (var num in shuffle(numArray)) {
      if (safeToPlace(puzzleArray, emptyCell, numArray[num])) {
        puzzleArray[emptyCell.rowIndex][emptyCell.colIndex] = numArray[num];
        if fillBoard(puzzleArray) return true; // exit upon success
      } 
    }
    puzzleArray[emptyCell.rowIndex][emptyCell.colIndex] = 0; // undo
    return false; // boolean - no success
}
```

The caller should check the return value, but if you start with a blank board, it is guaranteed to get `true` as return value. So you could do:

```
const puzzleArray = BLANK_BOARD.map(row => [...row]); // deep copy
const success = fillBoard(puzzleArray); // returns a boolean
// ... do something with puzzleArray ...
```

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Should I add a while loop to keep running the fill board on an empty board until it returns true? And then render the board?

Comment: No, like I wrote, if you give an empty board as argument, the function should always return true. If you decide to pass a partly filled in board (a real puzzle), then it could return false when there is no solution, and then it doesn't help to repeat it -- it will keep returning false.

Comment: Interesting, I added the following code after implementing your function and it's working properly: "  let success = false;

  while (!success) {
    success = fillBoard(NEW_BOARD);
  }"

Comment: Does it iterate more than once?

Comment: I'm receiving new boards every time, does that answer your question?

Comment: Sure, but my question is: does `fillBoard` ever return false so that a second iteration is needed? I was saying that it always returns `true` when you give it an empty board as argument, so the loop is not needed.

Comment: Oh you're right, the loop isn't needed. It never returns false